# Write results from imported .py file into text file

Tags: python, arrays, import

I have a .py file (array.py) that creates an array and prints it, and I want to import it into another .py file (write.py) and write the array to a text file (file.txt):

array.py is roughly like this:

```
def array(size, var):
    return array

def prettyPrint(array):
    for row in array:
        for col in row:
            print("{}".format(col), end=" ")
        print("")
main()
```

In write.py I have:

```
with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
     f.write("Some other info")

     import array as a
     a.main()
```

How do I write the array into file.txt? I tried several things, but f.write() only takes strings, and I need to keep my array together, neat and tidy. I feel like there's a way to use prettyPrint() but I'm not sure how (I'm pretty new at Python). What methods am I missing here?

Comment: Hi, there are sort of two parts to your question here.  The part about "from an imported .py file" is not really relevant here though.  The question you seem to be asking is how to write an "array" (is this "array" a plain Python `list` or something else?).  What format do you want to write it to a text file in and for what purpose?  A typical format for this is CSV which you can do with the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

Comment: The code you showed just opens a text file and writes "some other info" to it.  The rest of the code after that presumably doesn't do anything (though you didn't give the definition of your `main()` function.  The only thing `prettyPrint` does is print some text to standard output).  If you want it to be able to output to a different file you should take the file as an optional argument to the function and pass it to `print()`.  See [print](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print)

Comment: @Iguananaut Thank you! I didn't think of using csv.writer. That worked well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the array to a string or format it as you like.

```py
    # Convert the array to a string: [1, 2, 3]
    f.write(str(array))
    
    # Seperate each element: 1;2;3 (the seperator is ";" in this case)
    f.write(seperator.join(array))
```

If your array is multi-dimensional you can repeat this process for every array. (In this case you need to change the file-mode to `"a"` to append each array and not override everything)

```py
    # Loop through each array and seperate them: 1, 2, 3; a, b, c; x, y, z
    for array in arrays:
        f.write(seperator.join(array))
    
    # Example:
    seperator = ";"
    arrays = [
              [1, 2, 3],
              ["a", "b", "c"],
              ["x", "y", "z"]]
    
    for array in arrays:
        f.write(seperator.join(array) + "\n") # The \n appends a new line after each array
    
    # Output:    
    1; 2; 3
    a; b; c
    x; y; z
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a function in `numpy` - `np.savetxt` intended for these purposes :https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html.